# Emoji inconsistency in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, utf-8, emoji

In Google Chrome, if I create a prompt with an Emoji character, it looks fine there. But, if I put in an input field or in the page itself, all the characters look weird with a square and a cross.

Do you know if this is something I can fix easily?
Is it the charset used in the page (utf-8)?
Is it the font I'm using?

Thank you.

Prompt:
[image: Prompt]
Textarea:
[image: Textarea]

Comment: Hello. This is in a Windows 8.1.